# How to send token to API? in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, api, ionic3, outlook-restapi

I'm posting login details and receiving access_token for login Authorization but sending token back to web api for login approval is failing

```
getToken() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let name = this.UserName,
        psd = this.Password;

    let data = 'grant_type=password&UserName=' + name + '&Password=' + psd

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post('http://localhost:65882/Token', data, { headers: headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then((data: any) => {
                this.results = data; // get data in result variable
                this.token = JSON.stringify(this.results); // then convert data to json string
                console.log(this.token);
                this.allData = JSON.parse(this.token); // parse json data and pass json string
                console.log('token' + this.allData['_body{access_token}']); // got result of particular string
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.status);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    });
}
```

In console I'm getting details how to send token value to api and get login details or approvals[image]

Comment: Can you add the details of the API for the login endpoint?

Comment: `public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                // Adding.
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            // Return info.
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

If you use this make sure:
1. to pass correct content-type to headers:

```
headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
```

2. stringify the querystring like this :

```
 queryString.stringify({
          grant_type: 'password',
          username: auth.username,
          password: auth.password,
        }),
```

Comment: I'm getting token value but i need to send token value to API to get Authorization successful. How to get authorized and login to particular user type  depending on user type id. **Problem is How to read only token value and send it to API to get Authorization?**